# Confusion about some lines in "The Children's Song" by Rudyard Kipling

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

In Rudyard Kipling's [poem](http://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/childrens_song.html) "The Children's Song" from *[Puck of Pook's Hill](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lDgrcspPnUEC&ots=-qBWEUHVh3&pg=PA305#v=onepage&q&f=false),* what do the lines in **bold** mean?

> Teach us to rule ourselves alway,
>   Controlled and cleanly night and day;
>   **That we may bring, if need arise,
>
>   No maimed or worthless sacrifice**
>
> Teach us to look in all our ends
>   On Thee for judge, and not our friends;
>   That we, with Thee, may walk uncowed
>   By fear or favour of the crowd.

Comment: What research have you done? When you looked up the meanings of the words why did that not assist your understanding? How does the first half of the sentence (of which the quoted lines are the second half) affect your understanding of the words? Why have you left your homework so late?

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on EL&U, so you're not helping yourself by saying you need to hand in your assignment by tomorrow. You should follow Spagirl's tips if the question is to remain open.

Comment: related: [Confusion about a stanza from Rudyard Kipling](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17414/confusion-about-a-stanza-from-rudyard-kipling)

Comment: All of the words in the two lines carry their normal meaning. Please [edit the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/368740/edit) to answer Spagirl's comments (apart from why you have left it so late; we don't really need to know that, although it's something you may need to think upon). Please note that *literary analysis* is off-topic, but we can help you understand words or constructions where a dictionary is not sufficient. Once the question is bumped by your edit, it can be reopened.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just off the cuff, I think that the poet is comparing himself to an animal sacrifice. He means to say that whatever demands may be placed upon him (by virtue, patriotism, etc),  his efforts to meet those demands are comparable to the bringing of a sacrifice; and he prays that he may be ready to meet those demands properly. Perhaps the words “clean,” and “maimed” call to mind Scriptural requirements of the animal sacrifices which Jews offered to G-d in ancient times. Only clean species could be offered (e.g. cows, sheep, goats, and some birds, but not horses or dogs), and only healthy intact examples. For a discussion of these points please see Lev. 11:47, 14:4, 20:25, 22:18-25; Deut. 14:11-20, 15:21, 17:1

Comment: Is there any way to know why this answer was given a low score?

Comment: I haven't down voted you but I would guess it is because of the guidance on this site http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to only answer well asked questions. By the time you answered this @Aarushiyadav had been asked to improve his question and it had (I think) already been placed on hold.

Comment: I don't really know my way around the stack exchange. But my little experience here impresses me with how frustrating it is. One question after another meets with demands for clarification, when the original confusion is obviously sufficient to preclude this clarification. In your opinion, wasn't my response more useful than a plain request for clarification?

Comment: The point of the SE is not only to answer the queries individuals have, but to to build a library of detailed answers to every question about English language and usage. Answers that will help people other than the asker, in the future.  That requires the **questions** to be well written and specific. 'tell me what these lines mean' doesn't cut it in the way that (for the sake of argument) 'The lines appear to ask for permission not to bring a damaged sacrifice. This seems unlikely, is there something about the word order which changes the meaning?' might. http://english.stackexchange.com/tour